# Non euclidean distances of connected elements in binary matrix (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, geometry

> I have (3x4) M matrix  of connected "1" (connectivity 4 "North, South, East, West"), say:

```
M=[0 1 1 1;
   1 1 0 1;
   0 1 0 1];
```

> with index elements: idx=2 4 5 6 7 10 11 12; (8 elements). M can be viewed as a matrix of black and white pixels.
>
> Any idea to solve its (8x8) D matrix of white pixels separation?
>   (expl: elements with idx=2 and 12 are 6 steps apart= separated by 5 white pixels)

```
D=[0 2 1 2 3 4 5 6; 
   2 0 1 2 3 4 5 6;
   1 1 0 1 2 3 4 5;
   2 2 1 0 1 2 3 4;
   3 3 2 1 0 1 2 3;
   4 4 3 2 1 0 1 2;
   5 5 4 3 2 1 0 1;
   6 6 5 4 3 2 1 0]
```

Comment: Why are elements with idx=2 and 12 are 6 steps apart? Isn't it 4? Do you mean [Manhattan distance](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Manhattan_distance)?

Comment: allowed connexion are N,S,E,W through 1. connected elements via 0 is not allowed.

Comment: Also, is the problem computing the connected component, or computing the distance from that, or both? Your question is unclear

Comment: euclidean distance between elements with idx 2 and 4 is 1.414 (2 steps).euclidean distance between elements with idx 2 and 5 is 1.0 (1 step). So i don't know why this is unclear?

Comment: Can you explain how you get distance 6 between entries with idx 2 and 12? Or better yet, _define_ which distance you use. As I asked before: is it Manhattan distance maybe?

Comment: Suppose M is pixels matrix (1=white, 0=black pixel). So you have to travel only via white pixels from idx=2 to idx=12 with N,E,W,S directions.

Comment: I finally get it. You would rather make it clearer in the question text; it's hard to understand as it stands. You should mention it is _via white (nonzero) pixels_ only

Comment: Shouldn't the expected output be [this](https://pastebin.com/Rs2XKGtF)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a graph where nodes are nonzero elements, and edges connect neighbor elements. Adjacency list (list of connecting edges) for your example:

```
2-5
4-7, 4-5
5-2, 5-4, 5-6
6-5
and so on
```

Then use any algorithm to find all the shortest paths between all nodes.

[Breadth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) allows to find all the shortest paths from the first node, then from the second node and so on. Complexity O(V * E). Here E~V, so O(V^2)

[Floyd-Warshall algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm) is pretty simple - 3-4 code lines. O(V^3) - it is intended for weighted graphs.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. The problem with G(V,E) is that the adjacency matrix has VxV size (square lattice). It's too big for large graphs simulation.

Comment: Use adjacency lists instead of matrix as I have shown